# Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 Bluetooth Lag

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, intel-wireless, a2dp

Not sure why, but when I try to run bluetooth on a full install of ubuntu 16.04 (I have my reasons), the bluetooth speeds up and slows down and skips uncontrollably with no explanation in the debug logs i could find (tried setting bluetoothd to -d mode, but it spit out so much i couldn't sort through it all.) anyways, this is the only thing holding me back from enjoying this pc.

(BTW bluetooth works fine in live mode, but not in a full install)
(Also, wifi works fine as well.)

edit: bluetooth doesn't work in live mode either now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal I would do

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot

This will disable some power management on wifi and change the bluetooth coexistence setting since the default isn't working well

Comment: This seems to stop working after another reboot, then I have to apply it again.

Comment: Never mind, it turns out `blueberry` was making my bluetooth lag, and I removed it.